# spark createTableColumnTypes for TEXT data type in postgres table

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

In spark data set I'm using `createTableColumnTypes` for the database column data types to use instead of the defaults, when creating the table. It's working perfect for `VARCHAR(n)` but if I'm using `TEXT` it's throwing error. Code is written in Java

```
Dataset < Row > df = sqlContext.read()
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                    .schema(sparkDataSchema)
                    .option("delimiter", dataDelimeter)
                    .option("header", true).option("quote", "\"")
                    .option("escape", "\"").load(paths.split(","));


df.write().option("truncate", true).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("createTableColumnTypes", customSchema).jdbc(url, tableName, connectionProperties);
```

Error is given below

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:  DataType text is
>   not supported.(line 1, pos 29)

Comment: share the custom schema that you have specified.

Comment: @dassum custom schema is id long, name VARCHAR(150), comment TEXT

Comment: Please use the StructField("comment", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()) for comment column. TEXT type not supported by Spark.

Comment: @dassum yes I know I can use in StructField but I was finding another way to do through createTableColumnTypes option, anyway thanks for your input.